# Abode Flash Player 14 Active X "Failed to register" Error Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-7, windows, flash-player

I am trying to install Flash player 14 ActiveX plug-in for Windows 7 in Windows 8.1.

You might say Windows 8. 1 already has it but I have a program which specifically  needs the ActiveX plug-in for Windows 7 from the Adobe website.

It was fine until some days ago I could install Flash Player very correctly but now I get this error when installing flash player "FAILED TO REGISTER" every time and it's driving me nuts.   I need to install Flash Player so my program can use it.

I'm installing this `install_flashplayer14x32ax_mssd_aaa_aih`

And I also tried this solution on the [Microsoft website](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-windows_install/can-not-install-adobe-flash-player-error-messages/298dfdcb-277d-4457-94ce-fe3cdfca8cf1) using `subinacl` and `reset_fp11` but it doesn't seem to work,

> 1. Uninstall (clean) any of your adobe flash player files. See the instruction and file to download:
>      http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/141/tn_14157.html
> 2. Reboot your computer.
> 3. You must have administrator privileges to successfully complete these instructions.
>
> Warning! The following solution involves the Windows System Registry.
>   Editing or manipulating the registry incorrectly can result in serious
>   system damage which may require reinstallation of the operating
>   system.
>
> 4. Follow the instructions to download the SubInACL tool from the Microsoft Download Center.
>      http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=e8ba3e56-d8fe-4a91-93cf-ed6985e3927b&displaylang=en
> 5. Download SubInACL in a folder of your choice.
> 6. Download the reset_fp10.zip file. http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/494/cpsid_49419.html
> 7. Important: Be sure that both the subinacl.msi and reset_fp10.cmd files are in the same location (folder).
> 8. Double-click reset_fp10.cmd.
> 9. This will open a command window and execute the SubInACL tool.
> 10. Do not use the machine while SubInACL is running.
> 11. When it is finished you will see "Press any key to continue".
> 12. Install the Flash Player from www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer.

Does anyone have any other solutions to this?

Comment: Umm.. wait i have google chrome so will this unistaller remove flash of google chrome also. Also i already tried the 2nd method but the bat file is diffrent testing now.

Comment: No no I did all of the above steps 2nd time it's still giving me same error "Failed to register " -______- It's really pissing me off now.

Comment: Please be aware, installing flash player is a bad idea all around due to how insecure and exploitable it is.  All Chromium based browsers have a patched version of flash player built-in, so there should be no reason to have the standalone version installed.  What program are you using that requires it?

Answer (score 0):

The following from See https://forums.adobe.com/thread/910774
 worked for me. Though I just deleted the two directories he named.

1. Permissions must be set manually on
   `C:\Windows\System32\Macromed\Flash`  ( as Administrator -- right click on folder's name then launch Properties, switch SECURITY section and select your user. REMEMBER: your account must be administrator rights. check under Allow boxes there, then Apply all changes)
2. Same process must be done also for `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash`
3. Download latest http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/installers/archive/fp_11.1.102.55_archive .zip  it s an installer archive.
4. try to install `fp_11.1.102.55_archive\11_1r102_55_64bit\flashplayer11_1r102_55_winax_64bit.msi`   do not try to install exe versions. it doesn't work. MSI installer worked for me...